# How to route a path that ends with index.php in Slim framework

Tags: slim

I'm using Slim Framework 2.4.2 and my .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I've been having some trouble with routing a path that ends with index.php. For legacy support reasons, I need to be able to route `/soap/index.php` to my custom code, but it keeps going to my `notFound` handler.

I have a route like the following in my `/index.php`

```
$app->get('/soap/index.php', function () {
    echo "HERE";
});
```

However, when I go to `/soap/index.php` in my browser, it get Slim's 404 Not Found handler. I have tried changing the route to `/soap/index2.php`, which allows me to see "HERE" in the browser, but when I use `/soap2/index.php` I get the same results as for original. The `/soap/` directory does still exist, but `/soap2/` does not, so it doesn't seem that it is Apache causing the issue because both return the same results, the Slim 404 handler. It just seems like Slim gives a 404 for any route that goes to an index.php.

I've also tried creating just a `/soap/` route to see if Slim is trying to use that when I access `/soap/index.php` in the browser, but that still gives me a 404.

For now, I will try to just have the 404 handler detect the issue and perform the action.

Answer (score 0):

In the `notFound` handler, I am getting "/x.php" for the response from `$app->request->getPathInfo()`. As I add more letters to the front they end up in the string. It's clipping the first 9 characters, which is how long the filename is. After some more looking, this was a known bug.

It is reported on GitHub [here](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/979).

Updating to the newest Slim framework fixed the issue.